# Pass the key value pair to an API in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, use-effect, facet

I've perfectly working backend API which looks like this:

**Backend**

```
https://myapi.com/search?text=car&key=model&vlaue=Mustang
```

This api also works for **unlimited** `key-value` pair as well.
like this:

```
https://myapi.com/search?text=car&key=model&vlaue=Mustang&key=wheel&value=4....unlimited
```

---

**FRONTEND**

The `arguments` contains **data** which looks like this:

```
//arguments
[
  {model: "Mustang"}
]
```

**It also can be:Upto many more**

```
//arguments
[
  {model: "Mustang"}
  {wheel: "6"}
]
```

**CODE**

```
  const (arguments,SetArguments) = useState();

 useEffect(() => {
   console.log(arguments); //It return arguments.

//  arguments.forEach(item => console.log(item))

  let API = "https://myapi.com/search?text=car &key=model&vlaue=Mustang... "
  const res = await fetch(API);
  const {result} = await res.json();
}, [arguments]);
```

**PROBLEM:**

How do I pass those `arrays data` in `key-value` pair in useEffect to fetch data from that API ?

Comment: what do `data` and `arguments` arrays contain?

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code that this question is almost impossible to answer - can you post the code you actually use because this just won't run

Comment: @fullstack @StudioTime  I want to map the `arguments`  to pass into the API

Answer (score 1):

Assuming arguments is:

```
[
    {model: "Mustang"},
    {wheel: "6"}
]
```

Then you can go over each element, combine the key and value of the object with '=' and each element with '&'. Here is an example:

```
let API = "https://myapi.com/search?"


const params = arguments.map(i => Object.entries(i).map(([k,v]) => `key=${k}&value=${v}`)).join('&')

let APIWithParams = API + params
```

Comment: Actually it directly returning `key` and `value`.LIke this: `model=mustang` **but I want like** `key=model&value=Mustang`

Comment: Then you would want something like this:

`const params = arguments.map(i => Object.entries(i).map(([k,v]) => \`key=${k}&value=${v}\`)).join('&')`

> `"key=model&value=Mustang&key=wheel&value=6"`

If you had two objects in your array you would produce search params with duplicate keys. As suggested with the other answers instead of having an array of objects, perhaps have one object to store your arguments. 

`{model: "Mustang", wheel: "6"}`
Instead of
`
[
    {model: "Mustang"},
    {wheel: "6"}
]
`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the arguments as query parameters.
In your link you have some things behind the ?. These are query parameters. So you can pass the arguments like this:

```
`https://myapi.com/search?text=car &key=model&value=${argument}`
```

However it seems unnecessary to use an array for arguments, and it also makes it more complicated. I would suggest you have an argument object like this:

```
const arguments = {
  model: “Mustang”,
  wheel: 6
}
```

And then do this to fetch:

```
`https://myapi.com/search?text=car &key=model&value=${arguments.model}`
```

Otherwise you first have to map the array, and then find the object with key ”model” etc…

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your request, I have written code to generate key and value query String. Have a look!

```js
// return string containing key and value 
const generateQueryParams = (data, query) => {
  // iterate over each argument
  data.forEach((obj, index) => {
    // get key and value of each argument object 
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      let value = obj[key]
      // check if current argument is last in array, if yes then don't append & at the end of string
      if (index === data.length - 1) {
        // append key and value in query string
        query += `key=${key}&value=${value}`
        return
      }
      // append key and value in query string
      query += `key=${key}&value=${value}&`
    })
  })
  return query
}

// this will contain key value pair of arguments to send in API params
let query = "https://myapi.com/search?text=car&"

// mock data for arguments
let arguments = [{
  model: 'Mustang'
}, {
  wheel: 6
}]

// get the result
const result = generateQueryParams(arguments, query)
console.log(result)
```